# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. El proceso actual ha utilizado toda la capacidad de manejo del sistema para los objetos del gestor de ventanas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

tengo una aplicación hecha en WPF/c# Visual studio que crashea luego de unas 4 horas. Es una aplicación de llamada de tickets, que cada vez que recibe un nuevo ticket por socket server abre una ventana nueva y se reproduce un audio para la llamada de ticket, dura 10 segundos y luego se cierra. Uso timers, socket server e hilos.

Creo que la exception que tengo es la sgte.:
Exception type:   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message:          The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects

No estoy encontrando una solución para esto y no se a que apuntar o como buscar una solucion acorde a mi problema.

En esta parte del código abro la ventana de llamada:

```
       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread f = new Thread(delegate ()
                    {
                        Llamada_ticket lt = new Llamada_ticket();
                        lt.Show();
                        Dispatcher.Run();
                    });
                    f.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    f.Start();
                
                });
        }
            catch
            {
                log.Warn("Ocurrio un error al abrir la ventana de llamada");
            }
        }
```

Y lo cierro en Llamada_Ticket.xaml.cs con un timer:

```
       private void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dT.Stop();

            log.Info("Se cierra la ventana Llamada Ticket");
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código donde creas la ventana, y también donde la cierras?, lo mas probable es que solo las estés escondiendo y no matando el proceso.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver ya lo he agregado, muchas gracias!

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver ya lo he agregado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Traté de reproducir tu error. Creé un proyecto nuevo con su MainWindow y le agregué solo un botón que al presionarlo muestra otra ventanda (como Button_click). En la otra ventana inicializo un timer (System.Timers) el cual al finalizar me correrá lo que tienes en dt_Tick. Sin embargo, al llegar a this.Close() me provoca una excepción:System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'  Creo que seria importante que agregues un caso mínimo reproducible.